# Web deployment task failed. The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded. Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, publish

I am get error below on publish to azure using web deploy profile i downloaded from azure website

`Web deployment task failed. (The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS.)`

I am using visual studio 2012

Comment: What type of site is this? Free/Standard/etc? If you are using the lower end sites you might actually be out of connections and therefor can't publish since publishing requires a new connection.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue but after restarting management service it worked for me.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to your windows server where IIS Server configured.
2. Control Panel => System and Security => Administrative Tools => Services.
3. In the **Services**. Restart **Web Deployment Agent Service** and **Web Management Service**

Give a try now to web deploy.

Answer (score 1):

This may occur if you are connecting to the internet via a 3G dongle or card.

I have the same error and earlier in my warnings was "Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred" I'm stuck on a 3G connection today and getting this for the 1st time so presume these are related.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's been a long time ago, but I was struggling with the same issue lately. For me, it helped to restart the Web Management Service.
It might hang in Stopping status - if so, you can forcibly kill it:

First, open cmd with elevated privileges, and use `sc queryex wmsvc` command to find out the PID of the service.

Then, use `taskkill /PID [the pid] /F` command to kill the process. After that, you just start it again with `services.msc`

Hope it'll help :)

Comment: An identical situation happened to me. Web Management Service hang in Stopping status. I killed process with ```taskkill /PID [the pid] /F``` command and everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to publish a WebSite on Azure. I solved it by restarting the website from azure management. If you're deploying to IIS, I suggest to try a restart or a stop and start for your website and try publishing again.

Comment: This is a workaround. Not a solution. In order to get it working again you are restarting the remote site/service. However, the solution would be a way to avoid the problem in the first place.