# Web Deploy Fails with ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

When I deploy my solution (DNN solution) from Visual Studio using Web Deploy, I get success for a few files (averaging 30) then I get the error:

```
Error   102 Web deployment task failed. (The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded.  Learn more at: h**p://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS.)     0   0   h**p://mylocalhostwebsite/mywebsitename/"
```

I read everything I could get on the and was not able to find a solution that works.

I run my own dedicated server on Windows 2012 (on windows azure).  My dev environment runs on Windows 8, and I am deploying using VS.NET 2013 Ultimate

The server is clean, has only one website and it's not even life (no one is hitting the server except me, the one and only developer)

Once this error occurs, web deploy would fail with the same error continuously (no more 30 files or so)...all up until I restart the server.

I check the web server, and all seems to be intact...

I am not deploying the database as part of the process

Comment: Previously suggested answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227965/web-deployment-task-failed-the-maximum-number-of-connections-for-this-site-has

Comment: I did read this.  I tried this at home, from my mobile connection and from a Starbucks internet.   All gave me the same result.  They would work for a while, then I would have to restart the server to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an IIS in Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've solved it using this [post](https://iamrommel.wordpress.com/2014/09/27/error_exceeded_max_site_connections-solved/)

**UPDATE**

- Go to the IIS Server
- Select your IIS Server, in the Features View, select Management Service
- Under Actions, click Restart.

So I've restarted the server and worked fine...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12215778)

Comment: Thanks! @AndreiM for the suggestion.

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's a workaround. A way to recover once the problem occurs. The challenge is to figure out what _*causes*_ the problem so that it can be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

I tried searching everywhere for why this was happening, but am yet to find an answer.  When it happened, the quickest way to be able to publish again was to kill the WMSVC process and start it again.  To reduce having to do this manually, I kill the WMSVC process everyday at midnight, using a batch file and Windows Task Scheduler.

```
ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%B in ('tasklist /fi "Imagename eq wmsvc.exe" /fo csv') do @echo %%B >processkill.txt
set /p taskid=<processkill.txt
TASKKILL /f /pid %taskid%
exit
```

This creates a text file in the same location as the batch file you're running with the process ID of the WMSVC process, and then kills it.  Make sure to have the process set to automatic start.

Furthermore, I am investigating whether this will be a more permanent fix - adding the following to the registry:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3]
"MaxSiteConnections"=dword:00000010